Duplicate Requests in Next.js 14 with Parallel Routes and Intercepting Routes
I'm using Next.js 14 and encountering an issue where my requests are being duplicated when using parallel routes and intercepting routes. Here’s a simplified version of my RootLayout component:
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import Header from "./components/Header";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

async function fakeRequest() {
  try {
    console.log("fakeRequest");
    const resp = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
    const data = await resp.json();
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error", error);
    return null;
  }
}

export default async function RootLayout({ children, authModal }) {
  const data = await fakeRequest();
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <Header />
        {JSON.stringify(data)}
        {children}
        {authModal}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

I'm not using useEffect and the RootLayout component is only supposed to render once. However, the fakeRequest is being made twice. What could be causing these duplicate requests and how can I prevent them?.
Here is the full code
You can open the link and try reloading the page to see the issue.
Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

